# Jquery calculate months between 2 dates

Tags: jquery

What i would like to achive is if user puts in the date 
08/08/2016 to 08/09/2016  = 1 month
08/08/2016 to 01/09/2016  = 1 month
even 
08/08/2016 to 30/08/2016  = 1 month

So basicly if someone wants to rent a room from 01/08/2016 to 30/08/2016 that counts as 1 month

Could anyone help me achive this with jquery?

Or point me where to start.

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Looks good, going to look into it if i can manage to pull it off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this code.

Please note that while testing this; put the date in "MM/DD/YYYY" format i.e. US date format. I hope it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calc").click(function() {
    var from = $("#from").val();
    var to = $("#to").val();
    var monthDifference = 0;
    if (from != "" && to != "") {
      var fromDate = new Date(from);
      var toDate = new Date(to);
      calculateMonths(fromDate, toDate, monthDifference);
    }
  });

  function calculateMonths(fromDate, toDate, monthDifference) {

    if (fromDate < toDate) {
      monthDifference++;
      fromDate.setMonth(fromDate.getMonth() + 1);
      calculateMonths(fromDate, toDate, monthDifference);
    } else
      alert("monthDifference "+monthDifference);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
From:
<input type="text" id="from" value="08/08/2016"/>To:
<input type="text" id="to" value="10/08/2016"/>

<br/>
<br/>
<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using moment.js you can do this very simple way. You need to import moment.js file.

```
 // 31 Oct 2013 - 1 Feb 2014
> moment([2014, 1, 1]).diff(moment([2013, 9, 31]), 'months', true)
 2.983050847457627

 // 31 Oct 2013 - 31 Jan 2014
> moment([2014, 0, 31]).diff(moment([2013, 9, 31]), 'months', true)
3

// 31 Oct 2013 - 30 Jan 2014
> moment([2014, 0, 30]).diff(moment([2013, 9, 31]), 'months', true)
2.967741935483871
```